# how to add border radius on SVG path (javacsript)

Tags: svg

I could use a little help with setting border-radius on each side of rectangle . Here’s the current code rectangle svg path tag

```
`M0,53H415.4285583496094V57H0V53Z`
```

I want to give the each corner of the rectangle a rounded shape. How is it possible?
I am not able to apply like border radius properly. I already try using SVG path generator, but still not really understand how to use that to make such a border radius on that

Comment: Did you try to use a SVG path generator?

Comment: I did, but still not really understand how to use that to make such a border radius on that

Answer (score 1):

You can't apply a border radius on a `<path>` element.
But it can be set for `<rect>` [primitives. See Mdn Docs: rect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/rect#example).

You would define the border radius via `rx` and `ry` properties:

```
<rect x="0" y="53" width="415.43" height="4" rx="2" ry="2"  />
```

If you need to convert to convert a rect to a path element, you could use the [pathdata polyfill by Jarek Foksa](https://github.com/jarek-foksa/path-data-polyfill)

```
// convert rect to path
let rect = document.querySelector('rect');
let rectPath = rect.getPathData({normalize:true})
```

`{normalize:true}` will return an array of path commands using only a reduced set of command types (M, L, C, Z – with absolute coordinates).
This option can also be used to convert primitives like rect, circle, polygon, line etc. to path d data. So you will have to create a new path element an set the retrieved pathdata to the new path's d attribute.

```js
let path = document.querySelector('path')
//let bb = path.getBBox()
//console.log(bb)

let rect = document.querySelector('rect');
// convert rect to path
let rectPath = rect.getPathData({
  normalize: true
})
let newSvg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
newSvg.setAttribute('viewBox', '0 0 415.43 100');
let rectPathEl = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
rectPathEl.setPathData(rectPath)
document.body.appendChild(newSvg);
newSvg.appendChild(rectPathEl);


console.log(rectPathEl.getAttribute('d'))
```

```css
svg {
  display: block;
  width: 30em
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/path-data-polyfill@1.0.3/path-data-polyfill.js"></script>
<p>Path </p>

<svg viewBox="0 0 415.43 100">
<path d="M0,53 H415.4285583496094 V57 H0 V53 Z" />
</svg>

<p>Rect </p>
<svg viewBox="0 0 415.43 100">
<rect x="0" y="53" width="415.43" height="4" rx="2" ry="2"  />
</svg>

<p>Rect converted to path</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

A `<path>` element cannot really have radii at its corners. You can of course generate any kind of rounded path by defining suitable curve segments (`C` and `S` in the `d` attribute). Alternatively you can replace the `<path>` by a `<rect>` element, as I have done in the following snippet. I changed the height to 10 times the amount in order to make the rounding with a radius of `4` possible

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 500 100" fill="none" stroke="black">
<rect x="0" y="53" width="415.4286" height="40" rx="4" ry="4">
</svg>
```